# Discord js send messages to people who did not answer

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to make a command that sends a message to the players of a specific role who did not respond (with a reaction) to the last message in a channel

```
let channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
var listUserResponce = new Array();
var lastMessageToKeep = channel.messages.fetch({limit: 1}).then(messages => {         
    messages.first().reactions.cache.forEach(async(reaction) => {
//get user who react with specific emoji
       if(reaction._emoji.name === emojiAcceptedName || reaction._emoji.name === emojiDeclineName || reaction._emoji.name === emojiMaybeName){
          let list = await reaction.users.fetch();
           for(var [key,value] of list){
               listUserResponce.push(value)
            }
         }
    });
     return messages.first();
 }) 

//get user from role
message.guild.roles.fetch(roleId).then(role => {
     role.members.forEach(member => { 
//send a message to the users of the group who are not present in the list,
         if(!listUserResponce.includes(member.user)){
             lastMessageToKeep.then(function(result){
                 member.user.send(msgVote+result.url)
              })
          }
      })
 })
```

The listUserResponce is empty.
I am a beginner in node.js, I don't understand how to retrieve and keep the info. I tried with Promise.resolve but it doesn't work.

I tried to use the same method as for the lastmessage but I can't return the list of users. It is empty outside the foreach

Can someone help me / point me to the right way ?

I use discord v13.9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, I post it here if it can help other people

```
let channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelID);
   listUserResponse= new Array();
//use async in then for waiting Promise.all
   channel.messages.fetch({limit: 1}).then(async messages => {   
//waiting all async function      
      await Promise.all(messages.first().reactions.cache.map(async(reaction) => {
         if(reaction._emoji.name === emojiAcceptedName || reaction._emoji.name === emojiDeclineName || reaction._emoji.name === emojiMaybeName){
            let list = await reaction.users.fetch();
            for(var [key,value] of list){
               listUserResponse.push(value)
            }
         }
      }));

      message.guild.roles.fetch(roleId).then(role => {
         role.members.forEach(member => { 
            if(!listUserResponse.includes(member.user)){
                  member.user.send(msgVote+messages.first().url)

            }
        })
      })
   })
```